# How can I map a binary that uses bank switching in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly

Is it possible to memory map a binary that uses bank switching in IDA Pro?
I'm trying to reverse engineer a binary for the Motorola 6800 architecture. The full 64Kb binary is mapped to the upper 32Kb of the CPU's address space, and the high address pin is tied to one of the CPU's IO ports. The firmware can be switched between the upper and lower 'banks' via a trampoline section mapped to the same address in both banks.
I'm currently using two different IDA Pro files to work on the upper/lower 'banks', but it would obviously be better to consolidate the two files, since the two banks share common RAM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.